# Abort a pending serial.read() called in a parallel thread when the serial port gets closed in the main program

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyserial

I am currently developing a custom Serial monitor in Python using the Tkinter framework as GUI generator and the Pyserial library to handle low level communication. To receive serial data and plot the received byte on the program window I am using a parallel thread that keeps living till the **stop_serial_thread** variable is set to *True*.
This variable is set in the main program when I close the window program since the **closeSerialMonitor()** function is automatically executed.

If I run the program without a serial Port opened everything runs as expected and the thread exit properly. When a serial communication is ongoing the thread get stuck without never exiting, probably because the ser.read() never returns

I've already tried the followings without any success:

- serial read *timeout != 0*
- calling **ser.cancel_read()** to cancel pending reading
- creating a raise_exception method in the **serialPlotter** class to raise an exception and exiting the thread

What is the right way to properly close the thread and the serial port as soon as I want to close the program?

```
#comm.py

ser = serial.Serial()
stop_serial_thread = False

class serialPlotter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, monitor, autoscroll):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.name = name
      self.monitor = monitor
      self.autoscroll = autoscroll
            
    def receive(self):
        if(ser.is_open == True):
            chr = ser.read()                       # <----- blocking read
            self.monitor.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.monitor.insert(END,chr)
            if self.autoscroll.get() == True:
                self.monitor.see("end")
            self.monitor.config(state=DISABLED)
        
    def run(self):
        print ("Starting " + self.name)
        while(stop_serial_thread == False):
            self.receive()
        print("Ending " + self.name)
```

```
#serial_console.py

...

def closeSerialMonitor():
    
    ser.cancel_read()
    comm.stop_serial_thread = True
    ser.close()
    window.destroy()

...
```

Comment: The documentation says that when you create the port, you can set a read timeout.  So you'll need to check the result of `ser.read()` to see if any characters were actually read, but you'll be able to check your flag periodically.

Comment: In my Windows 10 with `pyserial` 3.5, both `ser.close()` and `ser.cancel_read()` will terminate the blocking `ser.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you close your application execute:

```
import sys  # Import the module sys in order to be able to use exit()

sys.exit()
```

> The sys.exit() function allows the developer to exit from Python.

I had the same problem some time ago with serial communication, and that's how I fixed it